# Xvfb with 32 bit color

Tags: ubuntu, colors, x-windows, xvfb, framebuffer

For some machines this works, for some it doesn't.

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x32
```

However, on most machines this works:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24
```

What is the secret ingredient to getting Xvfb working with 32 bit color?

Note: I'm running this on a Karmic box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success with using `vnc4server` instead

Comment: so.... the answer is "use vnc4server instead"?  and ... you couldn't just type this in the answer box there?